# Storing image in JQuery cookie or session

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, session, cookies

I am trying to store the base64 value of an image into a Jquery cookie.
This value is obviously pretty big but i need it in another part of my code.
(want to request the cookie in my C# code). When i try to request the value i get undefined even doh the same cookie with a random value does work. I do have the plugin installed to use $.cookie[].

```
$("#savebtn").bind("click", function () {
      var base64 = $('#sketch')[0].toDataURL();
      alert(base64); // right value
      $.cookie("img", base64);
      alert($.cookie("img")); // undefined
)};
```

When I use Session I am able to save the value, but I am not able to request that same value in my C# code.

```
$.session.set("image2", base64); 
alert($.session.get("image2")); // right value

var s3 = Request.Cookies["img"].Value; //value if i don't do the base64
var s4 = (Session["image2"]); //null
```

Does anybody have more information about this problem, I am not verry experienced with JQuery.

Comment: did you try setting the path to '/'? like `$.cookie("img", base64, { path: '/  });`

Comment: no, I am going to try that, what does that mean for the cookie if you set a path like that?

Comment: $.cookie("img", base64, { path: "'/" }); i did this and it did not change a thing

Comment: it sets the cookie route to '/', it sometimes worked for me, but I guess the case was that my paths were different, i.e. setting a cookie at `http://example/some/route` wouldn't work on `http://example/`

Comment: Just a warning here: Using cookie to store such a data is unsafe and not a good idea overall. More, it will slow down any post from client to server. Storing an encoded image Id recognized by the server would be a mutch safer/efficient idea. Even if it involves a little more work.

Comment: I will look into it, was simply looking at a good way to do it, thnx for the heads up